# Problem Setting Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to set a foreign key relationship between an Order_Items table and Parts table. I want to link the parts to products in the Order_Items table via foreign key. I have no issues doing this with other tables.

Here is how the Order_Items table is defined:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Items](
    [order_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [product_number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [quantity_ordered] [int] NOT NULL,
    [product_tested] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [order_id] ASC,
    [product_number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Items_Orders] FOREIGN KEY([order_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] ([order_id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Items_Orders]
```

and Parts table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parts](
    [part_number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [product_number] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [part_description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [part_tested] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Parts_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [part_number] ASC,
    [product_number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have tried setting the unique constraint on both product_number columns, but I still get the error message in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express as:

```
"The columns in table 'Order_Items' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restructuring my entire database to get this to work and streamlined the table connections.

Answer (score 3):

Question: if `[product_number]` in your `Parts` table can be made unique by a unique constraint - why isn't it the primary key by itself??

My gut feeling: `[product_number]` in `Parts` isn't really unique - only the combination of `(part_number, product_number)`, which is the primary key, really is unique.

If you **can** create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the `product_number` column alone, you should be able to create the FK constraint - try this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX01_Parts ON dbo.Parts(product_number)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Order_Items
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OrderITems_Parts
    FOREIGN KEY(product_number) REFERENCES dbo.Parts(product_number)
```

Does it work? If not - what error to you get, and where??

If that doesn't work, and only `(part_number, product_number)` is truly unique, then you need to reference both columns in your foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Order_Items
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OrderItems_Parts
  FOREIGN KEY(part_number, product_number)
    REFERENCES dbo.Parts(part_number, product_number)
```

and of course, this also means you need to have both those columns in your `Order_Items` table in order to be able to make the foreign key constraint work.

Just as a side note: having a compound primary key of two `VARCHAR(50)` columns and making that a clustered index on your `Parts` table is anything but optimal. If ever possible, try to make one or both of those "numbers" really a numeric type - e.g. an INT column. Or if that is not possible, think about having a surrogate `PartID` column (INT, IDENTITY) on your `Parts` table - that would make the FK constraint easier, too!

Comment: so having a PartID (INT IDENTITY) in Parts and then what would be the linking identity in the order_items table? I figured if I had the product_number with the part itself, it would logically link the two. Because Products are made up of parts. You can have many parts to one product.

Comment: @Jose Basilio: thanks - I was missing one of the many "E" in the "REFERENCES" keyword - fixed.

Comment: @Changeling: well, if the part_number completely and uniquely identifies the Part, then why is the primary key on (part_number, product_number) - doesn't make any sense at all. In that case, make your PK to be only (part_number) and reference that from your Order_Items table - problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this relationship to work, the Parts table cannot have composite key. In other words, you need to use product_number as the primary key since it is the column that they both have in common. You currently have part_number and product_number as your primary key.

Once you make that change, this statement will work:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Items]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Items_Parts] FOREIGN KEY([product_number])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parts] ([product_number])
```

Comment: Actually, yes you can have this scenario - if you **can** put a UNIQUE INDEX on Parts.product_number, then you **can** reference that as a FK from Order_Items, even if the PK is still (part_number, product_number). FK can **also** reference a unique index!

Comment: @Jose: This can't be correct because it makes Order_Items dependent on Parts. I think it would be the other way around. Since parts make up Orders. If you reverse Order_Items and Parts, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Changeling: you got your things mixed up here - Jose is totally correct. What you need to have is a reference from Order_Items to the Part - not the other way around! Each Order_Item has/is/ships exactly one Part, right?

Comment: @marc_s: No. Each Order_Item has products and products are made up of multiple parts

Comment: @Changeling: then where is the Products table?? you didn't mention any of that in your original question.... in that case, Order_Items should reference Products (which in turn then reference Parts)

Comment: @marc_s: I figured I could have an Order_Items table with multiple order_id's and products listed. That would then be linked back to the Parts table. The idea is that Order_Items will hold all the items for a particular order (major end items) and those major end items are then made up of parts, which are listed in the parts table.

Comment: @changeling: yes, but then your logical path would be: Order -> Order_Items -> Product -> Parts, and there's really no point in taking "shortcuts" to link order_items to parts directly - doesn't really make any sense at all....

Comment: @marc_s: I don't think I intended shortcuts and sorry if I wasn't clear initially.